# How do I get this magnet from under my refrigerator

Tags: retrieval

I dropped a magnet tonight and it fell in an enclosed space where can barely move it or slide it out from under my refrigerator. I've been trying to get it, but my hand is too big and it won't fit. What could I do to get it out?

Comment: Is the magnet lying on the floor or is it stuck to a ferrous part of the refrigerator frame?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve items from under a refrigerator?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/how-to-retrieve-items-from-under-a-refrigerator) If it doesn't, please [edit] your question to tell us how it differs.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use an even stronger magnet, like a neodymium bar magnet, to fish out the fallen magnet?

Comment: What are the chances that by doing this you will end up with two magnets stuck to underside of the refrigerator?

Comment: If the magnet is big enough, that would be a refrigerator stuck to a magnet, not a magnet stuck to the refrigerator.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like a back-scratcher, which is thinner than your hand, to reach under the appliance.

Turn it on its back with the 'fingers' facing upward. Then, maneuver the scratcher behind the magnet so that you can pull it toward you. It may help to put something under the 'fingers' so it is slightly raised to more firmly hold the magnet as you pull.

Good luck.

Comment: My first thought was wire clothes hanger, but the same principle. Bend as needed, hook over the magnet, pull.

Answer (score 2):

If the magnet is important and you must retrieve it, but cannot reach, or it is stuck to the fridge frame:

- switch off the fridge
- sidle it away from the wall and tip it backwards
- retrieve the magnet
- replace the fridge
- wait 4 hours for the refrigerant to settle before turning it on.